# Why Google's Webservice is returning approximate vs. rooftop or other location types?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, geocoding, google-geocoding-api

Regarding Google's Geocoding Webservice: Is there documentation (beyond Google's documentation), articles, or anything out there regarding how to format addresses to get accurate results.

Some of my locations have names preceding the address.  If it recognizes a street address in the string, I can usually get rooftop back.  In some cases having a single quote or special character in the name will cause it to just recognize the address and geocode rooftop.

However, I am also seeing cases where it finds the exact place correctly as an establishment, a church for example, but still says the 'location_type' is approximate.  Other cases where having words preceding the address causes it to only seem to recognize the zip code and it just geocodes the zip.

I am wondering if anyone has insight into how Google's Geocoding webservice API recognizes/parses locations?  What causes it to see the address in one case, but only see a zip in another?

Also, is there maybe a better way to interpret accuracy than just that 'location_type' field?

Comment: I'm assuming you've already checked out https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/, so if you can't find an answer there, I don't know where else you can look.

Comment: I am familiar with that documention, yes.  Thanks though!

Google is giving me results, and I am able to use those results.  I am trying to figure out if there is a better way I can manipulate my locations before sending them to Google in order to get better and more consistent results.

Comment: Did you try region/region code biasing or component filtering already?

Comment: I am experimenting with that, however I am not sure that I really want to bias or restrict my results.  I more want to understand how Google is parsing and looking at the addresses I am sending it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So basically you have to follow the standard mailing address format that is used by the respective country the address falls in and refrain from using apt/house/suite numbers. Use street number for the building/complex/entity rather than names. 
[This](https://developers.google.com/maps/faq#geocoder_queryformat) is what you need to go through. However, please do your research first and ask a question as a last resort.

Comment: Thank you for the link.  I should have seen that, and had not come across that yet in the research I did do.

I revised my question slightly to hopefully be more clear about what I am really asking.

If possible, I would really like to know how Google is dealing with input that is not ideal.

Comment: I'm afraid there's no specific answer available for that question. But if you think your query is totally clear and ideally it should return a proper location yet, it does not; you could report it here: https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/list

Comment: You are probably right.  I will report weird results if I feel I need to.  Thanks!